# Property of functional dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

If I have a relation R with schema S={A,B,C}, and I know that A->B. Does it mean that A,C->B is true? I know that the augmentation axiom tells me that A,C->B,C, but if two tuples, t1 and t2, agree on A and C, they specifically agree on A, which imply they'll agree on B. Does my reasoning ok? Is there more "formal" way to infer it?

Answer (score 2):

You can formally show that AC → B in two different ways.

First, the easy way, by applying the Armstrong’s Axioms:

```
1. A → B    (given)
2. AC → A   (by reflexivity)
3. AC → B   (by transitivity from 2 and 1)
```

Second, by proving it.

If A → B, then, in each instance r of R, ∀ t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub> ∈ r, t<sub>1</sub>[A] = t<sub>2</sub>[A] ⇒ t<sub>1</sub>[B] = t<sub>2</sub>[B]

This means that in each couple of tuples with the same value of A, you have the same value of B. In other words, the value of B depends only on the value of A. So, it is obviously true that for each instance r of R, ∀ t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub> ∈ r, t<sub>1</sub>[AC] = t<sub>2</sub>[AC] ⇒ t<sub>1</sub>[B] = t<sub>2</sub>[B], given that the tuples coincide on A.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that A,C->B is true?

Yes, it means that A,C->B. You showed by augmentation that A,C->B,C. A,C->B follows by decomposition. Also your argument is correct.

It happens that if you keep trying to apply every formal rule that you are allowed to assume to all the FDs that you have been given or generated so far until no rule generates another FD, then you will have generated every FD that follows from the given ones and no others, ie that hold when the given ones hold. Armstrong's are "sound" because they only generate FDs that hold given others that do and they are "complete" because they will generate all of them.

In practice, we can become good at intuitively finding derivations that an FD holds.